# How to show multiple rows in RDLC ReportViewer?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have multiple users in the database that some of them have multiple vacations, and some of them have only one vacation. In my report I have managed to show only one vacation for all users but for the users that have multiple vacation only the first vacation is shown.

I want to show multi rows if there is multi vacations and if not just one vacation then display it one vacation in one rows without any other rows?

In other words:

I want multiple rows to be added if there are multiple vacations, and if there is just one vacation then only one row should be shown?

[image]

Query Output as below

[image]

Dataset as below

[image]

Comment: you will need to provide more info. Please show and example of the output data from your dataset query. Also include details of the row groups, which column are being used for grouping.

Comment: [Query output](https://i.imgur.com/8JM982B.png) AND [DataSet](https://i.imgur.com/JgDQ7iM.png)

Comment: from your layout. it looks like you have placed the report data outside the details row/ group. Simply put the same data in the details group and it should show all the data that is returned by your query. (the row with the three horizontal lines is the detail row)

Comment: I tried deleting the Details group, the second vacation is now showing but it is shown in the next page. (One vacation in one page the second vacation is on the next page). The way it should be is that for the person that has multiple vacations both vacations should be on the same report page.Any advice?